# Branch created in bitbucket doesn't appear in GIT

Tags: git, bitbucket, branch

I'm slowly getting the hang of this GIT but stuck on this one...

Our workflow is to create a branch using the 'create branch' feature in JIRA. Go to the story, select 'create branch' which then takes us over to BitBucket where we can create the branch. I then see the new branch along with all of our other branches in bitbucket.

However, when I go to the command line on my machine to checkout the new branch, it can't find it. Using 'git branch -r' pulls the full list of branches I see in BitBucket...but not the one I just created.

Am I missing a key step here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do a `git fetch` to retrieve all references from the remote.

`git branch -a` lists all available branches.

Comment: Grrr...just when I think I'm *getting* git! :) That solved it! Thanks!

Comment: What would make this not work? As in, I have a branch on bitbucket, but git fetch and git ls-remote both fail to see it. I've refreshed the browser and switched branches in bitbutcket to make sure I'm not seeing a branch that's since been deleted, and it's still there.